# Getting UITapGestureRecognizer's sender in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

So I'm working on a selector that reminds users to pan the object instead of tapping it.
The following code is the animation:

```
func labelTapped(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer)->Void{
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: {
        sender.view.frame = CGRectMake(sender.view.frame.origin.x + 15, sender.view.frame.origin.y, sender.view.frame.width, sender.view.frame.height)
        }, completion:
        {(value:Bool) in
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {
                sender.view.frame = CGRectMake(sender.view.frame.origin.x - 15, sender.view.frame.origin.y, sender.view.frame.width, sender.view.frame.height)
                }, completion:
                {(value:Bool) in
                })
        })
}
```

now back to the object itself.  I'm allocating a `UITapGestureRecognizer` and adding it to the object, but i'm not so sure how it works, since back in Objective-C, we used to do:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(labelTapped)];
```

where no parameter is needed.  However in Swift, I'll have to put in a parameter in the parenthesis after `labelTapped`, as it will give me a `Missing argument for parameter #1 in call` error:

```
let labelTap1=UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: labelTapped())
```

How should I go about resolving this issue?  thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The action selector is a String ending in colon, which tells it there is one parameter (the sender):

```
let labelTap1=UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "labelTapped:")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleSingleTap:")
        tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)

    }

 func handleSingleTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        self.view.endEditing(true)

    }
```